# How do you say “I know how long I want it to be.” in French?

Tags: traduction

Scenario:

Anne has made a new friend named Jane. They both want to become closer and so they ask each other deep questions.

Jane: What do you want out of this friendship?

Anne: I don’t know but I know how long I want it to be.

Is it « Je sais combien de temps que je le veux être. » ? Lol, I see that this happens to be the literal translation which makes me think that it’s incorrect.

Comment: Generally, in English I wouldn't say about friendship, "I know how long I want it to be". It does not sound idiomatic for this context.  I think it is more plausible to say: I know how long I want it **to last**. How long do you want your trousers to be? How long do you want the class to be?

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for this! I can see now that It would indeed be more idiomatic to say **“I know how long I want it to last.”**

Comment: Ah, thank you for that. :)

Answer (score 5):

Durative "How long" is usually rendered by the interrogative adverb ***combien de temps***, or ***combien*** for brevity.

> I know how long I want it (to) last.
>
> *Je sais **combien je veux qu'elle dure***.

> She wonders how much longer she'll have to wait.
>
> *Elle se demande **combien de temps** encore elle devra attendre*.

> How long did you say they were spending in custody?
>
> ***Combien de temps** avez-vous dit qu'ils demeuraient en garde-à-vue ?*

I think French needs more words to achieve the same effect as your example :

> — Jane: *Qu'attends-tu de cette relation ?*
>
> — Anne: *Je ne sais pas ce que j'en attends, mais ce dont je suis sûre, c'est **combien je voudrais qu'elle dure**.*

Although *Jusqu'à quand* ("until when") works as well, it arguably doesn't sound as natural and might cause confusion in the absence of context : *je sais jusqu'à quand je veux qu'elle dure* (til death do us part? a specific event? etc.)

(P.S. ***Combien** je voudrais qu'elle dure* introduces the ambiguity that it could also mean *How ***much*** I want it to last*. If you mean to be specific about duration, use ***combien de temps** je voudrais qu'elle dure*.)

Comment: *Qu'attends-tu de cette relation ?* sounds very formal for a talk between friends. A more casual conversation would be more like *T'attends quoi de cette relation ? Je sais pas mais...*

Answer (score 0):

Je ne sais pas mais je sais combien de temps je veux que cela dure.

Ou « qu’elle dure » si on se réfère à l’amitié.